# where clause in LINQ to Entites DataBind

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to add a where clause to an existing LINQ DataBind but nothing I do works. The where clause I want to add checks if in the table refAuthSigner the column IsActive == 1.

Here's my existing Query:

```
// populates Authorized Signer dropdownlist
        using (dbPSREntities10 myEntities = new dbPSREntities10())
        {
            var allSigners = from refAuthSigner in myEntities.refAuthSigners <--- where clause somewhere around here??
                             select new
                             {
                                 refAuthSignerID = refAuthSigner.refAuthSignerID,
                                 refAuthSignerName = refAuthSigner.refAuthSignerFirst + " " + refAuthSigner.refAuthSignerLast
                             };
            ddlAuthSigners.DataSource = allSigners;
            ddlAuthSigners.DataValueField = "refAuthSignerID";
            ddlAuthSigners.DataTextField = "refAuthSignerName";
            ddlAuthSigners.DataBind();
        }
```

I want to add a where clause which is something like:

```
 var allSigners = from refAuthSigner in myEntities.refAuthSigners 
     where refAuthSigner.IsActive == 1
```

This code isn't right and just wondering how I would incorporate the where clause into the code. Thanks!

Comment: And what problem do you have when you add that `where` clause?

Comment: Operator of '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'. IsActive is type bit in SqlServer

Comment: Please edit the question to include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var allSigners = from refAuthSigner in myEntities.refAuthSigners
                 where refAuthSigner.IsActive
                 select new
                 {
                     refAuthSignerID = refAuthSigner.refAuthSignerID,
                     refAuthSignerName = refAuthSigner.refAuthSignerFirst + " " + refAuthSigner.refAuthSignerLast
                 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
where refAuthSigner.IsActive
```

Since it's a boolean value you cannot compare it to an integer.  It is `true` or `false`, not `1` or `0`.  (Some langauges conflate the two, C# is not one of them.)

There is no need to compare `IsActive` to anything.  `where` needs a boolean value, and `IsActive` is a boolean value.  You already have exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the statement:

```
var allsigners = refAuthSigner.Where(x => x.refAuthSigner.IsActive)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Operator of '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'. IsActive is type bit in SqlServer`

If this is the error you are getting try using `Any` instead of `Where` as it returns bool

Comment: Then he wouldn't be filtering the results, which is what he wants, he'd just be getting a boolean value, which is not what he wants.

Answer (score -1):

```
// populates Authorized Signer dropdownlist
        using (dbPSREntities10 myEntities = new dbPSREntities10())
        {
            var allSigners = from refAuthSigner in myEntities.refAuthSigners
                             where refAuthSigner.IsActive
                             select new
                             {
                                 refAuthSignerID = refAuthSigner.refAuthSignerID,
                                 refAuthSignerName = refAuthSigner.refAuthSignerFirst + " " + refAuthSigner.refAuthSignerLast
                             };
            ddlAuthSigners.DataSource = allSigners;
            ddlAuthSigners.DataValueField = "refAuthSignerID";
            ddlAuthSigners.DataTextField = "refAuthSignerName";
            ddlAuthSigners.DataBind();
        }
```